# Vector of number to string in hexadecimal format

Tags: c++, hex

I created a vector `std::vector<uint8_t> vec{ 0x0C, 0x14, 0x30 };`

I want to return the values of the vector in a string "0CD430".

I created this simple code:

```
std::string vectorTostring(const std::vector<uint8_t>& vec)
{
    std::string result;
    for (const auto& v : vec)
    {
        result += std::to_string(v);
    }
    return result;
}
```

in this case the result will be "122048". Wow the hex values are stored in the vector of bytes and why I got the decimal value and not the hex value using to_string?

Comment: numbers have different representations, but the value of `12` is the same value as `0x0C`. You are looking for output maniputlator `std::hex` to print the hex representation

Comment: There is no such thing as a "vector of hex". You have a vector of `uint8_t` initialized with 3 numbers written in hexadecimal notation. `{ 0x0C, 0x14, 0x30 }` is strictly the exact same thing as `{ 12, 20, 48 }`

Comment: clear, so I need to use a function that convert each element of the vector to hex before add it to result

Comment: @Edutox: Correct. Ultimately, the computer stores it as bits (binary); all other formats are alternative representations. Hex is used because it's exactly 4 bits per nibble, and there are exactly 2 nibbles in a `uint8_t`. See also ` std::to_chars`, which can work in hex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using a `std::stringstream` and some output manipulators like so:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string vectorTostring(const std::vector<uint8_t>& vec)
{
    std::stringstream result;
    for (const auto& v : vec)
    {
        result 
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(v) * 2)
            << std::hex << +v;
    }
    return result.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << vectorTostring({ 0x0c, 0x14, 0x30 }) << std::endl;
}
```

To take it in reverse order:

- `+v` promotes the `uint8_t`/`char` to `int`, so that it outputs the value and not the ASCII character.
- `std::hex` makes it output in hex format - but 11 becomes B not 0B
- `std::setw(sizeof(v) * 2)` sets the output width to double the number of bytes in a `v`-type - here just 1*2. Now 11 becomes " B".
- `std::setfill('0')` sets the fill character to 0, and finally 11 is turned into 0B.