# Why two rsa signatures are different from each other when one is generated by command and the other is generated by command？

Tags: c++, openssl, command-line-interface, rsa

I use the code below to generate a signature,then I use command line to verify it,and it verify failure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

int main() {
    FILE* pkey_file = fopen("private_key.pem", "r");
    if (!pkey_file) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening private key file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(pkey_file, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    fclose(pkey_file);
    if (!pkey) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading private key\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream input_file("data.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_file), {});

    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();

    if (EVP_SignInit_ex(ctx, EVP_sha256(), nullptr) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "Error initializing signing context\n";
        EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
        return 1;
    }

    if (EVP_SignUpdate(ctx, buffer.data(), buffer.size()) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "Error updating signing context\n";
        EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned int len = EVP_PKEY_size(pkey);
    std::vector<unsigned char> signature(len);
    if (EVP_SignFinal(ctx, signature.data(), &len, pkey) != 1) {
        std::cerr << "Error finalizing signature\n";
        EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
        return 1;
    }
    signature.resize(len);  // Resize signature to actual size

    for (unsigned char c : signature) {
        std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(c);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

The private key is below.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The content of file I sign is:

111111

And my public key is:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAujWddIWHz7uYYqnV/aOL
VYTYlXCgvozEn94WAPY7qAgD7CJHlizWONX/snwVjqiPD+DITEPjXa5MGf3WSFJG
Yk9yxd8bzr9JJFWt2P3Sg8RoaegJ9K5zrwQ1sdmBF7gBTN44TsEGYvNXoQ+faK+a
5kjzRy5LNwEeAWb06dNAEsQsVvY8LgxHoKIrLmaSTaDE0TW9bHiJ7xhAr2plPE86
yHGVqt9ZR+J2OrGdkM0jAfrg9ZzbniZkilUcaE1YqsVFfXff7Y0FPt2PoCd+bznc
ZjbyvR0mdLN5K5aVDHZYBheHR6xAqQjkRQ8mrHLTotSEeJpTfjev0byEIRSLDD6S
mwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The hex of signature generated by this code is:

```
9751cc93bbd0486efe89abe4872d52f6d71886815af1c2f3d13f92e3a4c636de86bdcfb9512ec4538a48f4798965f6c91845e7efc7a8bf20182bbd8d5d9632123dc79caa329ffa33eb2b333eaff64ea137e83e3deac3bcac6c177056deab198cfd548799c6adad3cde3359ba461185c82b2c25c574c31f473e95c8586826cf5991ae1687fdcb7c0ec2eb83510f494715994c21ffcca1b4af7e45fe7b678c6774c437b9b18af1f3c83f2a284961fc2e0ff9aebf1c9c8e373bcf8adc674c41c5b81f357988b39513d63da564d8d349d964d8dde879f66578f8fb2847c4e1c45ed287bca8b6344a6785b384f3d9b153e5ef5626db99056
```

And I generate a signature using commnad line,the difference I have highlighted below:

```
9751cc93bbd0486efe89abe48702d52f6d71886815af1c2f3d13f92e3a4c636de86bdcfb9512ec**0**4538a**0**48f4798965f6c91845e7efc7a8b**0**f20182bbd8d5d9632123dc79caa329ffa33**0**eb2b333eaff064ea137**0**e83**0**e3deac3bcac6c177056deab19**0**8cf**0**d548799c6ad**0**a**0**d3cde3359ba461185c82b2c25c574c31f473e95**0**c8586826cf599**0**1ae1687fdcb**0**7c0ec2eb83510f494715994c21ffcca1b4af7e45fe7b678c6774c437b9b18af1f3c83f2a284961fc2**0**e0**0**ff9aebf1c9**0**c8e373bcf8adc674c41**0**c5b81f357988b39513d63da564d8d349d964d**0**8dde879f66578f8fb2847c4e1c45e**0**d287bca8b6344a6785b384f3d9b153e5ef5626db99056
```

I tried two different system(Centos and Kail) get the same result;
And signature generated by command line can be verified and code can not.So I wonder why signature generated by code miss several 0 and how could I fix it.Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have one "command" too many in your title ?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to refer you to another answer I have given: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64551328/11829247

Basically what goes wrong is that when you print the value 11 you get "b", not "0b". You can fix this by adding `std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(c) * 2)` to your print - explanation is in the linked answer.